# Create a numerical column out of a url, with 1 for url present and 0 for all NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a column that would identify whether a url is present or not from an existing column called "links". I'd like all NaN values to become zeros and any urls to be denoted as 1, in the new column. I tried the following but was unable to get the correct values.

```
def url(x):
  if x == 'NaN':
    return 0
  else:
    return 1 

df['url1'] = df['links'].apply(url)

df.head()
```

[image]

Comment: `'NaN'` is a string in your function but an actual `NaN` value is not a string. Change to `if x == np.nan:` In other words, `'NaN'` does not equal `NaN` and you can use `np.nan` to return `NaN` instead of using `'NaN'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **pd.isnull(x)** instead of the **x == 'NaN'** comparison

```
import pandas as pd
df['url1'] = df['links'].apply(lambda x: 0 if pd.isnull(x) else 1)
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. But also take a look at David's solution, it seems much more readable than mine.

Comment: @rpa1111 kindly select cafeina or my solution as solution. If you are unsure whose to accept then kindly select one randomly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See my comment, but the simplest and most performant thing you can to do to get your desired output is to use a pandas method:

input:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'links' : [np.nan, 'a', 'b', np.nan]})

In[1]: 
  links
0   NaN
1     a
2     b
3   NaN
```

output:

```
df['url1'] = df['links'].notnull().astype(int)
df
Out[801]: 
  links  url1
0   NaN     0
1     a     1
2     b     1
3   NaN     0
```

`notnull()` returns `True` or `False` and `.astype(int)` change `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`, because `True` and `False` are `boolean` values with an underlying value of `1` and `0`, respectively, even though they say `True` and `False`. So, when you change the data type to `int`, it will show its integer underlying value of `1` or `0`.

Related to my comment `'True'` would also not equal to `True` and `'False'` not equal to `False` , just like `'NaN'` does not equal `NaN` (notice apostrophes versus no apostrophes).